# How to declare a style globally and use that style across the app in uwp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, uwp

I am using a style for a textbox in a page in my uwp app.The style I am writing in Page.resources tag. How to add this style globally and access in every page of app. But I want to use the style across the app by writing once. How can I do it.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="TextBoxstyle">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                              Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontStyle="Normal"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Text="&#xE10A;"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>

                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
            Grid.Row="1"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                      x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,8"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                      FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                  ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
            IsTabStop="False"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
            MinWidth="34"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>


        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyle}" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the styles in the App.xaml to make it accessible globally. You can add the style within the App.xaml like this:

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="TextBoxstyle">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" /> (the rest of your setters)...
        </Style>
    </Application.Resource>
```

Then you can call the style into any of your pages just like how you call it before. For example:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the style in App.xaml. You can access it on pages

```
<Application.Resources>
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
<!--Write your style here-->
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: means I have to use <App.Resources> right... and then using which key i can access?  for page level I am using style={staticResource stylekey}...